# How to get consent screen url frrom client id and client secret?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to get the user access token for a new project i'm working on,
I have managed to setup the consent screen and get the client id and client secret from Google developer console, but can't seem to figure out how to get the URL for the consent screen, which will prompt the user for authentication.
I'm using js.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#oauth-20-basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en

found it here, sorry for not digging deep enough